# White space appeared below menu

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I don't know how but suddenly white space appeared under website menu.

Please check website www.quoteradar.co.uk and help me I'm worried and have spent many hours.

Comment: Many times, leaving out all closing `?>` tags fixes this. I've seen it happen before.

Comment: Can you please point out how to fix? I'm new in this..

Comment: Almost impossible to tell without a sample of your code and a better explanation of what exactly the problem is.

Comment: What code you want to see? Actually when i load my website it doesn't show the page except a clickable whitepage and unordered dropdown menu but when you click on white space, you see the page at the bottom after huge space

Comment: See my answer below @user1830939

Comment: Use Webmaster tools such as [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to help and pinpoint troublesome elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a break in your WordPress theme.

Your mobile navigation menu is being displayed by default and looking through your `CSS`, it shows that there is nothing in place to hide it until the device resolution hits a certain point.

Your best choice would be to email/phone/contact [ElegantThemes](http://www.elegantthemes.com/) who are the developers of the divi theme that you're using and to request a fix from them. Considering its a paid theme, id expect support to be available.

Other than that we can't really help you as you the `CSS` is minified and would take a large amount of `CSS`, media queries and trial and error to get the page to work as it should

Comment: But actually problem remains the same with other themes too.

Comment: Do you have a demo of the other themes? Since the theme is a paid theme, the actual developers should be easily contactable and will be able to give you a much better explanation behind the problem and will be able to give you an exact fix. We don't have access to your theme and the editing behind it will take a long time. Images are missing too from the mobile nav.